# How is twitter.com's scaling background image implemented?

Tags: html, image

[twitter.com](http://twitter.com) has a nice implementation of a scaling background image.

How is this implemented? Is it using libraries/tools I could use myself?

What led me to look at this is that I'm looking for a solution which works well in older browsers and is simple to implement with light requirements.

Comment: This is actually quite interesting. It's the first time I notice how their background scales. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've create a fiddle for you that acts the same as the Twitter page.

Just to correct Talasan above, you need to remove from the code.

```
display:none;
```

Just to be more clear with your questions.
Twitter doesn't use any libraries or tools to achieve this. What they are doing is setting an image with fixed position on the center of the screen.
Why the image doesn't get resized while we resize the browser window?
They use a high resolution image and they resize it to 200% width and height. This way the image will look the same on almost all resolutions and will only change on really small ones.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vKYu4/1/)**

Also just to clarify this, Twitter's background image doesn't scale. It will look the same regardless the resolution of your browser but because of the way they are using to do this, you are getting the delusion that it is actually scaling.
See images below.

Actual Image Size

[image: Actual Size]

1920 x 1018

[image: 1920 x 1018]

1024 x 600

[image: 1024 x 600]

320 x 480 ( iPhone )

[image: 320 x 480]

Comment: This is exactly what twitter uses on the page that the OP pointed out.

Comment: By scale, I mean it changes in size dynamically as you resize the browser window.

Comment: @sync , Scaling would resize the image according to the browser window. Twitter's page is not scaling it is fixed. When you resize your browser's window the image stays fixed (doesn't scale) but you see a different part of the image ( starting from the top left ) exactly as it appears on the fiddle i have provided you.

Comment: @Thanos, that's only true to a point. Resize the window larger than the source image and it does scale up

Comment: @sync , i've added some SSs for different resolutions. As you can see it is not that the image is scaling up, it's more than the bigger your browser window the more of the original image you see.

Comment: @Thanos, thanks - I appreciate the time you're spending. But I feel like I'm missing something. The image is 1040 pixels wide, when viewed at 1920 you see the whole image edge to edge, so it's been scaled up by the browser to fit the view right? I.e. it never scales down, your viewport shows more of it as you say, but when the viewport is larger it scales up to fit keeping aspect ratio.

Comment: @sync Not exactly... Don't forget that we increase the image's size by 200% width and 200% height... That's 200% of the window's size.The reason they are doing that is to avoid the image of getting stretched depending on the browsers resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why they'd do it like this, but they're using a `fixed` position on a div that contains an image:

```
.front-bg {
    background: #000000;
    height: 200%;
    left: -50%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200%;
}
```

and then on the image, they're forcing it to 'fit':

```
.front-bg img {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Though, you should probably just use the background-size property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: I don't think you tried the background of Twitter on different window sizes.

Comment: @MoayadMardini it acts differently, sure, but what's the point?

Comment: When you try that you'll see that your answer doesn't do what the OP asked for. I didn't downvote your answer though.

Comment: background-size looks cool but the browser support is not good enough for my project, twitter's approach seems more browser compatible

Comment: @sync gotchya, good luck then :)